# Gurobi warm start barrier method

Tags: gurobi

I know that if we are doing things like column generation in Gurobi, we will get better performance by warm starting the solver before each iteration.

[Here](http://www.anlak.com/2016/09/warm-start-linear-programs-with-gurobi.html?m=1)'s a blog post I found on warm starting simplex method, which sets `PStart` and `DStart` before optimization. But AFAIK, these two attributes are only used in Simplex method, but in my problem I am using barrier method. Is there a way to warm start in barrier method?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. It is a bit sad because in general warm-starting interior point methods is very challenging. The challenge is related to the central path which makes the initialization counter intuitive.